# Boisik and \cdots

Tags: fonts

I found that `$\cdots$` appears as white-space in the PDF output while using the boisik font. Here is a minimal example:

```
 \documentclass{article}  
 \usepackage{boisik}  
 \begin{document}

 $A \ldots B \cdots C \cdot D \cdotp E$

 \end{document}
```

`\ldots` and `\cdot` are printed correctly while a small space is printed for `\cdotp` and three times that for `\cdots`. (`\cdots` is defined as `\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp` in `tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx`)

Have I forgotten something while using boisik?

Thanks.

Comment: From the 'manual' of `boisik`: *Current status of Boisik is an alpha version. Many features are missing*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package misses the redefinition of `\cdotp` according to the different slot assigned to `\cdot` with respect to the OMS encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boisik}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\cdotp}{\mathpunct}{symbols}{"79}

\begin{document}

$A \ldots B \cdots C \cdot D \cdotp E$

\end{document}
```

[image]